# Are there any plans to add paid software support to Kubuntu's Muon Software Center?

Tags: kubuntu, software-center

I was wondering if there are plans to add support for purchases in Muon Software Center just like there is in Ubuntu Software Center?
That would be handy, and as Muon developer is part of Kubuntu team, I think this makes sense... 
But does anybody knows whether there are concrete plans?

Comment: Are you two twins :) ?

Comment: Lol.. I have 2 mail accounts linked into askubuntu... thought they would appear as a single account here...

Answer (score 3):

Amusingly both USC and Muon don't use Launchpad for blueprints: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/muon so it's hard to tell directly if there are any plans. Then again the paid for services are offered by the ubuntu-one 'online services' team, so it is probably they and not any other team or project that would have the plan at all.

Asking on #ubuntuone I found an answer that ubuntuone development has no plans for kubuntu. I'll also ask in the USC people to see if they know anything, but for now, assume no.